# Google Calendar Sync changing meeting organizer of recurring appointment in Outlook 2010

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization, outlook

In Outlook 2010 I have created a recurring meeting with my non-gmail e-mail address. After a Google Calendar Sync, Outlook does not recognize me as the organiser anymore. If I look in Google Calendar it says "Created by 'gmail e-mail address'". It seems Google Calendar is changing the meeting organizer to the Google Calendar e-mail address.

Now, I need to reschedule the recurring meeting, but Outlook is not letting me, because he does not think I am the meeting organizer. Does anyone know how to fix this and how to prevent this in the future?

Comment: Are you using 2-way sync with Google Calendar, or 1-way?

Comment: 2-way. I can image this problem would go away with 1-way (outlook -> google calendar), but I'd like to continue using 2-way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy answer here besides having to recreate the recurring meeting.

There are a few Google Product forum discussions on the issue, but no good resolution. The only certain fix (for events in the future) is to turn on 1-way sync (Outlook --> Google)

Here is one of the latest threads [about the issue](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/calendar/W1gx0prrz_c/6R5WXX5xr_w) (with no resolution).

You can try using this VBScript, but this is not an official solution. I would test this out on a few test meetings first: https://sites.google.com/site/esillybin/code/changetheorganizerofoutlookmeeting (credit: Tom Weber who is the listed author of this Sites post)

Relevant code:

```
Public Sub CalendarRecurringItem()
'Below is just creating variables and declaring their types 
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application 
Dim objMsg As Outlook.AppointmentItem 
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection 
'Below sets the objects to Outlook and whatever items you have selected 
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection 
'Below the For Each statement is going through each item you have selected in case you selected more than one calendar item 
For Each objMsg In objSelection 
'Below is showing you a message box and saving your response in a variable named "answer" 
answer = MsgBox("Are you the Organizer of " & objMsg.Subject & "?", vbYesNoCancel) 
'Below is going through the three possible answers from the question above 
Select Case answer 
Case vbYes 
objMsg.Parent.MeetingStatus = olMeeting 'This sets the MeetingStatus to olMeeting which is equal to 1 

objMsg.MeetingStatus = olMeeting 'This sets the MeetingStatus to olMeeting which is equal to 1 
Case vbNo 
objMsg.Parent.MeetingStatus = olMeetingReceived 'This sets the MeetingStatus to olMeetingReceived which is equal to 3 

objMsg.MeetingStatus = olMeetingReceived 'This sets the MeetingStatus to olMeetingReceived which is equal to 3 
Case vbCancel 
End Select 
objMsg.Save 'This saves your change to the meeting item 
Next 


'This clears the variables so you do not mess up anything else by leaving values in the variables. 
Set objMsg = Nothing 
Set objSelection = Nothing 
Set objOL = Nothing 


End Sub
```

Comment: This creates a workable situation for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem happened to me in Outlook 2010. The above did not quite work for me... So I used mfcmapi.exe from Microsoft.

1. Start `mfcmapi.exe`
2. *QuickStart* → *Open Folder* → *Calendar*
3. Sorted the appointments by "From" so I would only find appontments that were organised by me
4. Then going through the list, only selecting those calendar items with To: includes other people, select a Calendar item.
5. In the *Property* pane below, look for two data elements:

   1. Tag:`0x802E0003` Type: `PT_LONG` — this value should be = 1 (Smart View: Flags: `asfMeeting`) — The incorrect value = 3 which includes `asfReceived`.
   2. Tag: `0x805A0003` Type: `PT_LONG` — this value should be = 1 (Smart View: Flags: `respOrganized`) — The incorrect Value = 3 which is `respAccepted`.

With these saved it worked, even without restarting.